# IBM Access Client Solutions script that opens a read only Excel file and update a cell

Tags: java, xml, macros

We recently updated from IBM Personal Communications iSeries to IBM Access Client Solutions, so I'm having to update a bunch of our VBScript macros to IBM XML HAScript / Java.

I can get as far as extracting info from the screen, but I'm stumped about how to get the script to open an Excel file as read only, populate the info into Cell B2, and leave the file open for the user to view.

Here is what I have so far, which only reads the info from the screen and then stops:

```
<import>
    <type class="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell"/>
    <type class="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row"/>
    <type class="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet"/>
    <type class="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook"/>
    <type class="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory"/>
</import>

<vars>
  <create name="$Company$" type="string" value="" />
</vars>


<screen name="Screen1" entryscreen="true" exitscreen="false" transient="false">
    <description >
        <oia status="NOTINHIBITED" optional="false" invertmatch="false" />
    </description>
    <actions>
        <extract name="&apos;Extract&apos;" planetype="TEXT_PLANE" srow="3" scol="15" erow="3" ecol="16" unwrap="false" continuous="false" assigntovar="$Company$" />
    </actions>
    <nextscreens timeout="0" >
        <nextscreen name="Screen2" />
    </nextscreens>
</screen>

<screen name="Screen2" entryscreen="false" exitscreen="true" transient="false">
    <description >
        <oia status="NOTINHIBITED" optional="false" invertmatch="false" />
        <numfields number="141" optional="true" invertmatch="false" />
        <numinputfields number="0" optional="true" invertmatch="false" />
    </description>
    <actions>
    <nextscreens timeout="0" >
    </nextscreens>
    <recolimit value="10000" />
</screen>
```

It seems like Apache POI may be my best bet for opening and manipulating the Excel file, but I just can't figure out the proper coding for getting it to run from the XML HAScript. Any help would be greatly appreciated.